# Handling audio / video ontimeupdate Events in Meteor.js

Tags: events, meteor, html5-audio

im working on a Meteor.js (v. 1.0.0) Web Application that handles Video and Audio. For a certain case I need the HTML5 *audio.ontimeupdate()* Event to trigger, but seeing as only *click, dbclick, focus, (...)* are handles with the standard Meteor package, I am having problems triggering this Event.

Is there a Possibility to trigger this Event otherwise?

Here is a Code Sample:

radio.js

```
Template.audioPlayer.helpers({

    audio:function(){
        audioSource = videos.findOne({_id:Session.get("playlist")[Session.get("queue")]});
        myAudio = new Audio();
        myAudio.src = audioSource.source;
        return audioSource.source
    }
});

Template.audioPlayer.events({   

    'click #mainPlay':function(){          
          myAudio.play();
     },

     'click #mainPause':function(){         
        myAudio.pause();
     },

     'myAudio.ontimeupdate':function(){
        console.log("Current Track Position is: " + myAudio.currentTime);
     }      

 });
```

In this case i would like the program to simply log the current position of the audiofile. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's better to put the audio element in the DOM like this :

```
<template name="myAudio">
  <button type="button">Play</button>
  <audio src="{{audioSource}}"></audio>
</template>
```

Then you can control it using JS :

```
Template.myAudio.helpers({
  audioSource:function(){
    var video=videos.findOne({_id:Session.get("playlist")[Session.get("queue")]});
    return video.source;
  }
});

Template.myAudio.events({
  "click button":function(event,template){
    template.find("audio").play();
  },
  "timeupdate audio":function(event,template){
    console.log(template.find("audio").currentTime);
  }
});
```

You can set a Session variable in the event handler to update reactively a DOM node if you want to display the current time in your app.

Comment: restructured my Code, now works with the Console :) Thank you! Great Tip!